# Understanding do.call() treatment of 'paste' versus 'function(x) paste(x)' on data frame rows

Tags: r, do.call

I'm confused as to how do.call works.

```
dat <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
                  v2 = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Why does this seem to pass one row at a time

```
do.call(paste, dat)
[1] "a a" "a b" "b a" "b b"
```

but this doesn't

```
do.call(function(x) paste(x), dat)
Error in (function (x)  : 
  unused arguments (v1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), v2 = c("a", "b", "a", "b"))
```

The function that I want to use is

```
paste_ <- function(x) paste(unique(sort(x)), collapse = "_")
```

I do realise that I could just use `apply` to get what I want, but was trying to understand what `do.call` was doing.

```
apply(vars_comb, 1, paste_)
```

Comment: the error tells you--`function(x)` defines an argument called x, and you're passing v1 and v2 since you have a named list (data frame). you could do `do.call(function(...) paste(...), dat)`
or `do.call(function(v1, v2) paste(v1, v2), dat)` etc

Comment: But that sorting and unique-ing is not going to work because `paste` will never know about the content of each row at the same time. You'd be better off melting to a long dataset, unique, sort, then collapse using paste as an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to do.call is a list, and dataframes are lists.  So `do.call(paste, dat)` is equivalent to:

```
paste(v1=dat$v1, v2=dat$v2)
```

Whereas the function you defined only accepts an "x" parameter.  So the second part is equivalent to:

```
my_paste <- function(x) paste(x)
my_paste(v2=dat$v1, v1=dat$v2)
```

Which gives you the same error, because v1 and v2 aren't defined.

However, you can see that the following does work:

```
do.call(function(...) paste(...), dat)
```